# Can I start the National College with all my cities having libraries then settle a third city?

Tags: civilization-5

Can I start the National College with all my cities having libraries then settle a third city?

If I do that, I won't satisfy the "each city requires a library" constraint.
What happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(tl;dr version in bold)

There are many national wonders that require a certain building in all of your non-puppet cities, the National College being one of them.

If you complete the wonder and only then settle a new city, there is no problem - the wonder is still there even if the new city is missing the required building.

If you are in the middle of the wonder construction, **the construction will halt**, and you will be forced to choose a different production project. **However, the wonder construction will retain its progress**, so once the new city gets the required building (and that can happen immediately, if you just buy it), you can continue working on it from the point you stopped. Well, technically there is a production "decay" - I believe that **if you don't continue working on the wonder for 50 turns, then it starts slowly losing progress**. I always manage to get those buildings long before the decay kicks in, though.

As an aside, as far as I know, the production decay is not exclusive to interrupted buildings. If you just switch a construction project by your own volition, it also applies - the progress will remain for 50 turns (10 for units), and then decay.

This is different with interrupted world wonders; you cannot continue working on them, so instead you are reimbursed with gold.

Comment: Oh. Is this something that's changed, or was this always the case?

Comment: @DMA the fact the progress is retained? I think it was always the case. It's the same with technologies btw, if you switch your research, old research progress will remain (and I don't think technology progress decays).

Comment: I knew it was the case for tech's and units. Somehow I thought National Wonder progress was lost... but maybe not :/

Comment: Not worth a separate question, but what if construction on the NC completes *before* a third city is founded?  Does it become defunct until the new library is built or does it hum merrily along?

Comment: @Ben the wonder works fine. My 3rd paragraph above addresses exactly that.

Comment: @Oak — Mea cupla; I must have been distracted by the shiny, bold text.  ;-)

Comment: @oak, does it increase the amount of production required? Normally national wonder production cost scales with the number of cities. Does this change at all if you found a new city half-way?

Comment: @Joe yes, I'm pretty sure the cost is increased when you go back into producing it.